# Visual Studio 2017 and MySQL EntityFramework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

When adding a new `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` > `EF Designer From database` > `New Connection` > `Change Connection` I do not see MySQL as an option;

[image]

I have installed NuGet package MySQL.Data.Entity (as well as the required MySql.Data and Google.Protobuf).

Also when I add the package MySQL.Data.Entity, my existing MS SQL entities returns this error message;

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Inheritance security rules violated by
>   type: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices'. Derived types
>   must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be
>   less accessible.'

Yet in the App.config it is still pointing to MS SQL;

```
<add name="MyDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyEntity.csdl|res://*/MyEntity.ssdl|res://*/MyEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MSSQLSERVER;initial catalog=MyDB;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

If I remove the NuGet package MySQL.Data.Entity and change nothing it works correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved just today the same error uninstalling all MySQL and re-installing (in the same order):

- 1.- [mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.7](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/)
- 2.- [mysql-connector-net-6.8.8](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.8.html)

And, in the VS project, installing with the Nuget package manager:

- 1.- Entity Framework v.6.0.0
- 2.- MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity v.6.8.8

I had been proving another versions and never the MySQL Data Source had seen until select this combination. I hope it's work for you. Regards.

NOTE: I have Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Since the links don't show all versions, other versions can be found here: [MySQL for Visual Studio](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/visualstudio/) and [MySQL Connector NET](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/)